# Solidity function returning manager address of 0x00000 after contract deployment in Remix IDE

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix, metamask

I have recently ran into a bit of an issue with a solidity contract I created and am trying to deploy and interact with inside of the Remix IDE. The function I have written to return the address of the contract manager is as so

```
 function getManager() public view returns(address){
    return manager;
}
```

The way the contract manager is set is as so

```
 function Contest() public {
    manager = msg.sender;
}
```

I have created two JavaScript compile and deploy scripts which I run inside of my terminal. The deploy script is written as this

```
 const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const {interface, bytecode} = require('./compile.js');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    'MetaMask Mnemonic',
    'Infura endpoint key'
);



const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
    const accounts =  await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    console.log('deploying from ', accounts[0]);

    const ABI = interface;

    const deployedContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(ABI))
    .deploy({data: bytecode})
    .send({
      gas: '1000000',
      from: accounts[0]
    });
    console.log('contract deployed to', deployedContract.options.address);
}

deploy();
```

Once my contract is deployed I receive the deployed address (something like 0xbc0370FbC085FAf053b418e6ff62F26ED2C7Dee1) and then I go over to the Remix IDE where I put in the address and use the Injected web3 option. However when I call the "getManager" function it returns an address of 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 and I can't seem to get it to return the address of the manager. This method was working once before and I cannot seem to figure out why it's not working any longer.

Comment: What is the full source?

Comment: @RaghavSood full source of the project is right here on my github if you need to take a look  https://github.com/danwise91/Blockchain/tree/master/GiveAway_Blockchain

Comment: Well, that should work. You mentioned you are using the injected web3, are you testing on a testnet? If so, did you wait for the transaction to be mined before querying? You can get the address even when the tx is pending, but you won't be able to use the contact until it has been mined

Comment: I'm actually testing in the Remix IDE not on testnet. Before when it was working I would get the address from the console after it deploys and then it would work and I could return the address of the manager as soon as I would deploy the contract at the address I received inside of Remix.

Comment: [0xbc0370FbC085FAf053b418e6ff62F26ED2C7Dee1](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xbc0370FbC085FAf053b418e6ff62F26ED2C7Dee1) seems to be a valid contract deployed today on the Rinkeby testnet, so looks like your web3 is connected to that. Try changing it from Injected Web3 to javascript VM, that should let you test locally.

Comment: still not really working...still getting the same address back and not the address it was deployed to

Comment: Hard to say without more details on your setup, but the contract itself looks alright